# How to change a random element of an attribute?

Tags: java, string, random

I'm trying to select a random element in an attribute, and then reverse the value of that randomly selected element between 0 and n, and then reprint the whole attribute again, with the reversed element shown. The reverse value for 0 is 1, and for 1 is 0 in this case.

Here is what I've attempted:

```
    String whatever = "11111";
    int n = whatever.length();
    //the UI class generates a random integer number between 0 and n
    int p = CS2004.UI(0,n);


    if (whatever.charAt(p)=='0') {
        += 1;
    } else {
        += 0;
    }
```

I'm lost on the adding the opposite number bit.

I should clarify that this is homework!

Comment: what is +=1 in your code ??

Comment: What do you mean by "attribute?"

Comment: @Kakarot nothing. I don't know which String variable to assign the 1 or 0 to.

Comment: @David Ehrmann a string variable like whatever for example. Sorry, should've worded it better.

Comment: `int 5 = whatever.length()` ?

Comment: oops, that should've been n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java, but you could do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(whatever);
if (whatever.charAt(p)=='0') {
    sb.setCharAt(p, '1');
} else {
    sb.setCharAt(p, '0');
}
whatever = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yours and Watto's were the same, but I have to give to you because you answered earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Basic `StringBuilder` usage with a ternary operator produces what you're looking for:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.append(whatever.substring(0, p));
result.append(whatever.charAt(p) == '0' ? "1" : "0");
result.append(whatever.substring(p + 1, whatever.length()));
System.out.println("Result = " + result.toString());
```

As others have noted, using the [`StringBuilder.setCharAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29) method produces a more concise answer (with the ternary operator added, this is the shortest answer so far):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(whatever);
result.setCharAt(p, whatever.charAt(p) == '0' ? '1' : '0');
System.out.println("Result = " + result.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, lets give this a try.

Firstly, you will need to change the name of your variable `5` - I don't think you're allowed to start variables with a number (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html))

I'm assuming that by 'attribute' you mean the length of the `String`? This is probably supposed to be the value of your `5` variable.

So, lets look at some modified code...

```
String whatever = "11111";
int n = whatever.length();

//the UI class generates a random integer number between 0 and n
int p = CS2004.UI(0,n);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(whatever);
if (whatever.charAt(p)=='0') {
    sb.setCharAt(p, '1');
} else {
    sb.setCharAt(p, '0');
}
whatever = sb.toString();
```

This code will change the value of the character in position `p`, and then convert it back to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Java are immutable so you need to first convert them to some mutable structure before modifying them.

If you are trying to flip the characters at some position in a code then this code might be of help :

```
String whatever = "11111";
char[] charArray = whatever.toCharArray();
int n = whatever.length();
//the UI class generates a random integer number between 0 and n
int p = CS2004.UI(0,n);


if (charArray[p]=='0') {
    charArray[p] = 1;
} else {
    charArray[p] = 0;
}
```

Then you can modify whatever characters you wish to. Once you are done you can reconstruct a String from the charArray as follows :

```
String result = new String(charArray);
```

This can also be achieved using StringBuilder.

Comment: You mean "convert them to some **mutable** structure"

Comment: StringBuilder has the added benefit of being a CharSequence (like String), so charAt() and length() are both methods on it.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann What point are you getting at ? Are you trying to compare the efficiency of char array vs StringBuilder ?